# Logging into syslog from a new service in systemD

Tags: python, logging, service, systemd

I created a new service in systemD, so far it does not do anything, I am just trying to check that everything is running step by step.

For that, I am adding logs, however, it does not appear in Syslog, which I understand is the default for services.

When I use simple prints in my code, it does appear in Syslog though

```
import logging
class recoveryService:

        def __init__(self):
                self.id = 'integ38'
                print self.id # prints to log
                logging.info("the id is {}".format(self.id)) #does not print to log


        def run(self):
                print 'reached run' #prints to log
                logging.info('reached run log') #does not print to log    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    recovery = recoveryService()
    recovery.run()
```

How can I make these loggings appear in syslog?

Comment: ["Note that the root logger is created with level **WARNING**."](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel)

Comment: the final process of the system may be your process. Dependency and necessities must be ensured (sometimes the system can't do these things at once). use **update-rc.d**. the programming language you use and the priorities you use don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logging.getLogger().setLevel('INFO')` call this once before your first logging call. The default level of the root logger is `WARNING` so no logs below that level are shown. Also be aware that it is good practice to define a handler or use [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) to set up your logging.